# Facelets: Page Not Getting Rendered

Tags: tomcat, jsf-2, richfaces, facelets

I am using JSF 2 and RichFaces in Tomcat. I am a beginner and trying out a page I found [here](http://richfaces-showcase.appspot.com/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=panelMenu), but the page is just blank (contents not being rendered). I try to add the Facelets 1.1 libraries and the page is rendered without a problem. However, I read somewhere that with JSF 2, Facelets libraries are not necessary as they are included by default. Also, when I add the Facelets libraries, other pages are being affected where I start getting a message like 
***"library supports namespace: http://java.sun.com/jsf/html, but no tag was defined for name: head"*** for a page that was working ok without the libraries.
I also included the following libraries in my /WEB-INF/lib directory:

1. richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar
2. richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
3. richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar
4. richfaces-ui-3.3.3.Final.jar
5. jstl.jar
6. standard.jar

For simplicity, my code is here (some sections removed so that it is not too long).

NB:When i insert some plain text inside h:form or h:panelGrid, it is rendered without a problem.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<style>
    .cols {
        vertical-align: top;
        }
</style>
<h:form id="form">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="cols,cols" width="400">
        <rich:panelMenu style="width:200px" mode="ajax"
            iconExpandedGroup="disc" iconCollapsedGroup="disc"
            iconExpandedTopGroup="chevronUp" iconGroupTopPosition="right"
            iconCollapsedTopGroup="chevronDown">
            <rich:panelMenuGroup label="Group 1">
                <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.1"
                    action="#{panelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                    <f:param name="current" value="Item 1.1" />
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
                <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.2"
                    action="#{panelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                    <f:param name="current" value="Item 1.2" />
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
                <rich:panelMenuItem label="Item 1.3"
                    action="#{panelMenu.updateCurrent}">
                    <f:param name="current" value="Item 1.3" />
                </rich:panelMenuItem>
            </rich:panelMenuGroup>
        </rich:panelMenu>
        <rich:panel bodyClass="rich-laguna-panel-no-header">
            <a4j:outputPanel ajaxRendered="true">
                <h:outputText value="#{panelMenu.current} selected" id="current" />
            </a4j:outputPanel>
        </rich:panel>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you add jsf 2.0 libraries?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.faces-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
```

And configured your web xml like this?

```
<servlet>

<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
```

```
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
```

Comment: Hi,jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar were added with Java EE 6 Libraries both are Implementation-Version: 2.0.3-FCS from their MANIFEST.MF files. web.xml has the configurations indicated above. But I am not sure where to add the dependency?

Comment: Are you  to using tomcat 6 or 7. İf 7 you dont need to do anything. It has to work. İf 6 you have to change the old libs in tomcat directory with mojarra libs

Answer (score 0):

There's library conflict in your libraries, but I'm not sure it is related to the problem you're referring to.

You should NOT have both of the following libraries in your project:

- richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar
- richfaces-impl-jsf2-3.3.3.Final.jar

They include similar set of classes. If you're using JSF 2, remove richfaces-impl-3.3.3.Final.jar from your classpath.